# Pandas series substring starts and ends with letter

Tags: regex, pandas, string, filter

I have a large pandas series containing approximately half a million rows of this form:

```
pd.Series(['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            'consectetur adipiscing elit',
            'quis euismod mi, id venenatis urna',
            'curabitur vel augue viverra diam imperdiet laoreet'])
```

and I would like to filter the series by words that start and end with a specific letter. For example, if start letter is 'l' and end letter is 'm', then I want to include rows that have 'lorem' as substrings, or rather '^l.*m$'.

So I need to split my string into substring and do .str.contains('^l.*m$'), however I don't know of an optimised way to do this.

Comment: You could match the words with `\bl\w*m\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, can you please provide an answer? I tried s.str.contains('\bL\w*m\b') and I don't get any matches, when I should get row 0 which contains Lorem.

Comment: Try it like this `print(s.str.contains(pat = r'\bL\w*m\b', regex = True))`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, this worked, thanks. Do you know what the performance is? I'm wondering how it would perform for a large set of data.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no answer about the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundaries matching from L to m `\bL\w*m\b` and in between match 0 or more word characters.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
           'consectetur adipiscing elit',
           'quis euismod mi, id venenatis urna',
           'curabitur vel augue viverra diam imperdiet laoreet'])
s = s.str.contains(pat = r'\bL\w*m\b', regex = True)
print(s)
```

Output

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```